Prevent zooming "out of bounds" in mobile browsers
When the user pinch-zooms (i.e. changes the visual viewport) on pages whose content is initially smaller than the screen, they can scroll to empty areas where there's nothing, not even <body>, instead of seeing more of the page contents.
Can this unnecessary scolling to empty areas be prevented?

<html>
<body style="width: fit-content;">
<div style="background-color: yellow; width: 200px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</body>
</html>

Solutions that aren't ideal:

Updating the elements' coordinates to follow the visual viewport around causes them to jitter on some devices and doesn't prevent the unnecessary scrollability.
Replacing the default pinch-zoom action by a custom zoom function also might cause jitter on some devices.
Disabling zoom would prevent users from increasing the font size etc. and is against Web Content Accessibility Guidelines. Offering zoom buttons instead is not so intuitive because users expect to be able to zoom by pinching.
Disabling scrolling would also prevent scrolling to useful content (for example after zooming or on small screens) (as opposed to scrolling to empty areas, which is what I want to prevent).


The trick is to use the viewport metatag, then you shouldn't get this weirdness at all. After that, don't handle zooming in any special way - no matter how clever you are you are going to break expectations if you do anything special for your accessibility users who can't have any of that "interpret what the developer tried to do" nonsense.

@somethinghere Use the viewport metatag with what content exactly? Also I don't understand the last sentence - are "accessibility users" users who use certain accessibility features, what problems do you mean by "can't have".

Your idea of zooming something for the user of responding to their zoom, don't do that. And yes, I mean people who actually use those features for accessibility aren't clamoring for your clever solution that they don't know how to use because it's not the default. And regarding content, you shouldn't get a body with a weird width if you use the basic ones like width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover. This kind of "behaviour" only really happens on sites without mobile support.

@somethinghere The viewport metatag with the content you give doesn't solve the problem. And regarding the <body>: I made it small just to illustrate that scrolling happens beyond everything, even beyond the <body> and beyond <html>. The problem occurs also with a normal <body>.

@somethinghere As said, the problem occurs also with a normal <body>. Just remove style="width: fit-content;" and you'll see.
